# Lock screen on Linux-based screens

Tags: linux, unix, gnome, kde-plasma

Is there a lock screen on Linux-based systems?

When the screen is locked, the user should enter a **PIN** code to enter back. Like the PIN screen lock on an iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are looking for a tool or library to do this. There are quite a few DE independent options:

1. [xlock](http://www.tux.org/~bagleyd/xlockmore.html)
2. [slock](http://tools.suckless.org/slock)

They are opensource so you can take a look at code if you are looking for a programatic way to do this.

For library you can look at xlib for all interaction with X. [XLockDisplay](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/XLockDisplay.html) is the function that you might want to use.

Comment: Can you please provide also some libraries that are doing such staff.

Comment: Updated my answer to add library reference.

Answer (score 2):

Gnome Desktop:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

What this actually does ([source code](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-screensaver/blob/master/src/gnome-screensaver-command.c)) is call a DBUS Api that aims to be desktop-neutral. Read more about that on [this page](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)

Answer (score 0):

Often you have that choice in the screen saver. Then the computer will be locked after a specific time that you decide. You have it in Ubuntus screen saver.